# Проблемы с консолью. Спам console.clear(). Не открываются глобальные объекты

Tags: google-chrome, консоль, обработка-ошибок, google-chrome-devtools

Доброго времени суток, сегодня обнаружил большую проблему в консоли(недавно обновлял chrome) начался спам командами [image: console.clear]console.clear(). В таком количестве очень раздражает и мешает разработке на том же JavaScript. Так еще перестала открываться мини-вкладка с глобальными объектами.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поиграть с настройками консоли. Выберите те пункты, которые вам нужны, например `errors` и `warnings`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]